# How to disabled fullscreen button on MacCatalyst

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, mac-catalyst

[image: UIWindow on macCatalyst with close, minimize and fullscreen buttons]

Currently, I have this to stop resizing window:

```swift
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 480, height: 900)
windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.maximumSize = CGSize(width: 480, height: 900)
#endif

let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
self.window = window
window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

but the **fullscreen** button makes it full screen anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit complicated but possible. Here is an approach (I dropped all target macros to simplify post).

Result:

[image]

Code:

```swift
// on next event after UIWindow has made key it is possible to find NSWindow in runtime

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        ...
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()

        DispatchQueue.main.async { // < wait for NSWindow available
            SilentBridge.disableCloseButton(for: self.nsWindow(from: window))
        }
    }

// added helper function to SceneDelegate to find NSWindow

    func nsWindow(from window: UIWindow) -> NSObject? {
        guard let nsWindows = NSClassFromString("NSApplication")?.value(forKeyPath: "sharedApplication.windows") as? [NSObject] else { return nil }
        for nsWindow in nsWindows {
            let uiWindows = nsWindow.value(forKeyPath: "uiWindows") as? [UIWindow] ?? []
            if uiWindows.contains(window) {
                return nsWindow
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Objective-C part is preferred (it's just simpler to work with non-declared selectors). Add new Objective-C class via Xcode template and confirm creating bridge. Afterwards it is needed to add below class header file in generated `*-Bridging-Header.h` and all should work.

```c
// SilentBridge.h

@import Foundation;

@interface SilentBridge : NSObject
+ (void)disableCloseButtonFor:(NSObject  * _Nullable)window;
@end

// SilentBridge.m

#import "SilentBridge.h"
@import Foundation;

// Forward declarations to allow direct calls in below method
@interface NSObject(SilentBridge) 
- (id)standardWindowButton:(NSInteger)value;
- (void)setEnabled:(BOOL)flag;
@end

@implementation SilentBridge

+ (void)disableCloseButtonFor:(NSObject *)window {
    if ([window respondsToSelector:@selector(standardWindowButton:)]) {
        id closeButton = [window standardWindowButton:2];
        if ([closeButton respondsToSelector:@selector(setEnabled:)]) {
            [closeButton setEnabled:NO];
        }
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: @Mc.Lover, code in answer does not use `NSWindow` class, it is your bug.

Comment: Do you have a sample project somewhere? I cannot make fullscreen button disable!

Answer (score 7):

Here is another approach that does not need Objective-C, selectors, or asynchronous calls. It also does not need target macros, iOS will simply skip `if let NSApplication`. Paste it into your view controller that appears first. Note that this disables the green full-screen button on all your windows. If you want to differentiate, use ideas from Asperi's Swift part.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    func bitSet(_ bits: [Int]) -> UInt {
        return bits.reduce(0) { $0 | (1 << $1) }
    }

    func property(_ property: String, object: NSObject, set: [Int], clear: [Int]) {
        if let value = object.value(forKey: property) as? UInt {
            object.setValue((value & ~bitSet(clear)) | bitSet(set), forKey: property)
        }
    }

    // disable full-screen button
    if  let NSApplication = NSClassFromString("NSApplication") as? NSObject.Type,
        let sharedApplication = NSApplication.value(forKeyPath: "sharedApplication") as? NSObject,
        let windows = sharedApplication.value(forKeyPath: "windows") as? [NSObject]
    {
        for window in windows {
            let resizable = 3
            property("styleMask", object: window, set: [], clear: [resizable])
            let fullScreenPrimary = 7
            let fullScreenAuxiliary = 8
            let fullScreenNone = 9
            property("collectionBehavior", object: window, set: [fullScreenNone], clear: [fullScreenPrimary, fullScreenAuxiliary])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why Apple is asking us to du such things ? Did your code pass the Mac App Store review ? Basically it works.

Comment: @MarcT. The Catalyst app I did this on is in Objective-C, above is only from my Swift test project. And yes, it then passed the Mac App Store review repeatedly. Why they ask for it, and why they don't provide the means to do what they are asking, is anybody's guess.

Comment: this is great, where you have `let resizable = 3` I changed it to `4` and when they click the green button it goes to the maximum size I have set, not full screen, because when it was `3` it could not be resized. Not sure what the numbers mean, I tried a few numbers until I found what I liked.

Comment: @KurtLane [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowstylemask/nswindowstylemaskresizable?language=objc) is the documentation for the 3 (actually 1<<3 = 8). 4 (1<<4 = 16) marks it as a subclass of `NSPanel`, I am not sure what that would mean in a Catalyst context.