# Disable close button and miniaturize window in MAUI MacCatalyst application

Tags: c#, swift, maui, mac-catalyst, xcframework

I have a MAUI app (exclusively for MacCatalyst). I need to work with a C# library so I cannot rewrite it in Xcode.

I want to gray out the close button and miniaturise the window at app launch. I know how to achieve it inside a C# Cocoa app, but not in a MAUI MacCatalyst app. This code is the code that works well for the Cocoa app :

```
NSWindow window = NSApplication.SharedApplication.MainWindow;
NSButton button = window.StandardWindowButton(NSWindowButton.CloseButton);
button.Hidden = true;
window.SetIsMiniaturized(true);
```

I want to achieve the same thing in my MAUI MacCatalyst app.

I know it is possible to miniaturise and disable the close button in Swift like this for example:

```
guard let nsWindows = NSClassFromString("NSApplication")?.value(forKeyPath: "sharedApplication.windows") as? [AnyObject] else { return }
for nsWindow in nsWindows {
 nsWindow.setIsMiniaturized(true)
 nsWindow.standardWindowButton(.closeButton).setEnabled(false);
 }
```

But I cannot find a way to do it in the MAUI project, as `NSClassFromString` is unknown from MAUI.

I have tried to do it in a native swift framework (distributed as `MacWindowManager.xcframework`), that I can call through a native binding library.
But there seem to be a limitation somewhere, as the native binding works fine when I try it with a simple function like this

```
@objc public func TestAdd(i:Int, y:Int)-> Int{
        return i + y;
    }
```

However when I introduce a function regarding a code like this

```
guard let nsWindows = NSClassFromString("NSApplication")?.value(forKeyPath: "sharedApplication.windows") as? [AnyObject] else { return }
```

everything compiles but the MAUI MacCatalyst app is not launched.

I tried using the package `Dynamic` in the native library, but no luck either

```
@objc public func SetUpWindow(uiWindow:UIWindow){
   let window = Dynamic.NSApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.hostWindowForUIWindow(uiWindow)
   let button = Dynamic(window).standardWindowButton(Dynamic.NSWindow.ButtonType.closeButton)
   Dynamic(button).setEnabled(false)
   Dynamic(window).setIsMiniaturized(true)
}
```

I have seen the possibility of creating a `MacOS bundle` like in this article about [Disabling the Mac Zoom/Maximise Button in Catalyst](https://crunchybagel.com/disabling-the-mac-zoom-maximise-button-in-catalyst/).
The thing is I don't know how to embed a `MacOS bundle` into a `.xcframework`.

Has anyone succeeded in calling `AppKit` functionalities from a swift framework, linked through a native binding project to a MAUI MacCatalyst application ?

Or do you have any idea regarding why it is not working ?

Or do you know a way to achieve this directly with MAUI ?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59749105/how-to-disabled-fullscreen-button-on-maccatalyst?rq=1) for example shows how to disable the maximize/minimise button, but I cannot make it work for Maui.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize?view=net-maui-8.0) to control the windows. Here is the sample to change the size of the window in MacCatalyst.

```
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WindowHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(
        nameof(IWindow), (handler, view) =>
        {
            var size = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(width, height);
            handler.PlatformView.WindowScene.SizeRestrictions.MinimumSize = size;
            handler.PlatformView.WindowScene.SizeRestrictions.MaximumSize = size;
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    handler.PlatformView.WindowScene.SizeRestrictions.MinimumSize = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(100, 100);
                    handler.PlatformView.WindowScene.SizeRestrictions.MaximumSize = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(5000, 5000);
                });
            });

        });
```

Comment: Thank you, I already fixed the size of the window. What I need is to disable the close button (gray out) and miniaturise the window, and the handler does not enable that, do you have any idea?

Comment: I found that the `NSWindow.PerformMiniaturize` method is used to minimize. But it is based on NSWindow not on the UIWindow. `Handler.PlatformView.WindowScene` is an instance of `UIKit.UIWindow` and I try to search for the method based on UIWindow to disable the close button but cannot find something useful.

Comment: Guangyu Bai, Thank you for your time, I appreciate. Yes, those methods to miniaturise and disable a top left button are based on the `NSWindow` and in MAUI we have the `UIWindow`. There is some code to get the `NSWindow` dynamically but it uses `NSClassFromString`, which is available for MacCatalyst in Swift, but not in Maui. It is possible to achieve what I want in a Swift MacCatalyst app, hence the idea to use a native binding , but I cannot have it working with Maui.